# Why does the casting of classes not work in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, casting

I send such list to the function: `listOf(IncomeVerificationType::class, IncomeType::class)`, but function returns the map only with `"id"`.  Why is `is` not working? What am I doing wrong?

Function:

```
    fun sendUpdatedEvent(model: Model, updatedFields: List<Any>): Map<String, Any> {
        val fieldToValueMap = mapOf("id" to model.identity.id)
        updatedFields.forEach {
            when (it) {
                is IncomeVerificationType -> fieldToValueMap.plus("incomeVerification" to model.incomeVerification)
                is IncomeType -> fieldToValueMap.plus("incomeTypeId" to model.incomeTypeId)
            }
        }
        return fieldToValueMap
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `IncomeType::class` is *not* an instance of `IncomeType`.
The type of `IncomeType::class` is `KClass<IncomeType>`. It references the class itself, not an instance of the class.

To correctly match those class objects in a when statement you can use the regular equality checks instead of the 'is' check:

```
    val list = listOf(IncomeVerificationType::class, IncomeType::class)
    list.forEach {
        when (it) {
           IncomeVerificationType::class -> println("IncomeVerificationType")
           IncomeType::class -> println("IncomeType")
        }
    }
```